# Proper Rx Operation for Merging two observables

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

I wrote a below class for accessing my repo that is included both remote repo and local repo.

```
public class VenuesRepoImpl implements VenuesRepo {

private VenuesLocalRepo venuesLocalRepo;
private VenuesRemoteRepo venuesRemoteRepo;

public VenuesRepoImpl(VenuesLocalRepo venuesLocalRepo, VenuesRemoteRepo venuesRemoteRepo) {
    this.venuesLocalRepo = venuesLocalRepo;
    this.venuesRemoteRepo = venuesRemoteRepo;
}

@Override
public Observable<List<Venue>> getAllVenues(String ll, int offset) {
    return Observable.merge(venuesRemoteRepo.getAllVenues(ll, offset)
                    .doOnNext(venues -> venuesLocalRepo.addVenues(venues)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
            venuesLocalRepo.getAllVenues().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
}



@Override
public void deleteAllVenues() {
    Completable.fromAction(() -> venuesLocalRepo.deleteAll()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

}
```

}

but `Observable.merge` duplicates my item, it has both api and db items. How can I access db items just when api is not available?

Comment: Doesnt directly answer your question, but if you declare your db as your single source of truth you won't have to deal with this issue, you would show db data all the time and update it as necesarry with data from api

Answer (score 3):

You should use `concat()` instead of `merge()`.

You could follow this pattern:

```
// Our sources (left as an exercise for the reader)
Observable<Data> memory = ...;
Observable<Data> disk = ...;
Observable<Data> network = ...;

// Retrieve the first source with data
Observable<Data> source = Observable
  .concat(memory, disk, network)
  .first();
```

More info [here](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)